# How to get all children and their values from a Window containing Tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

**EDIT**

> > Straightforward question

I have been trying for the past 2 days I could find a way to fetch all the children along with the data from a TabControl which has multiple TabItems in it. it looks like this

[image]

The TABULAR TabControl has three TabItems (TEMPERATURE, TEMPERATURE1, AND PRESSURE) each TabItem contains textboxes and sliders. I want to loop through TabItems fetching all the textbox values and slider values.

I have tried the following methods but I was only able to see the data in properties when I add the variables to the watch window in debug mode.

> METHODS I'VE TRIED

```
int tabular_items = TabularJsonEditor.Items.Count;
                sock.sendData(tabular_items.ToString());
                foreach(var rh in TabularJsonEditor.Items.SourceCollection)
                {
                    string h = rh.ToString();
                    var coll = TabularJsonEditor.SelectedContent;
                    
                }
                var iEnumeratorOftoBeIterated = TabularJsonEditor.Items.SourceCollection.GetEnumerator();
                while (iEnumeratorOftoBeIterated.MoveNext())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The current value is: {iEnumeratorOftoBeIterated.Current}");
                    var curr = iEnumeratorOftoBeIterated.Current;
                    //var res = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(curr);
                    var rest = ListBindingHelper.GetList(curr);
                    var temp = GetVisualChild(0);
                    
                }
```

> WATCH WINDOW

[image]

Comment: when a question doesn't have a [mcve], a bounty doesn't make it any better. removing something resembling [mcve] before adding a bounty is a new level, though. and [mvvm] tag usage is another mistery

Comment: You must use data binding. Everything else is not reasonable. Data binding will make your problem look trivial.

Comment: It makes no sense at all to iterate through ui. Bind your itemssource of the tabcontrol and template tab viewmodels out into the tabs. Then you've got all your data in your viewmodels.

Comment: you are trying to use the textbox.text property to story your value. This is not the way to go. Either do it properly using MVVM pattern. or at least have a class containing all your values and update your gui if any of these values changes

Comment: What is your desired output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to get child controls, and [test type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) of child

```
static public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        if (childVisual is Slider slider)
            Debug.Print(slider.Value);

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        EnumVisual(childVisual);
    }
}
```